# json request not working in IE and issue with cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, getjson

The following code works only in Firefox, but not in IE. 
The word "Meanscoil na mBraithre Criostaí" brakes the JSON file:

```
"2028425":[19, "Awaiting Correction", "", "Meanscoil na mBraithre Criostaí"],



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ticketsearch').click(function() {
    var ticketcode = $('[name=ticketcode]').val();
    $.getJSON('/import/envelope.json', function(data) {
      $('.ticket').text(data[ticketcode][3]);
      $('.envstatus').text(data[ticketcode][1]);
      $('.track').text(data[ticketcode][2]);
      $('.track').attr("href", data[ticketcode][2]);
    });
  });
});
```

PS> How can I clear cache after each JSON request.

Comment: Specifically what about it does not work in IE? Side comment: the selector `$('[name=ticketcode]')` is quite inefficient. You should pair that selector with an element type; e.g. if the element is an `input` then use this selector instead: `$('input[name=ticketcode]')`.

Comment: +1 for Matt's comment.

Also, your data will always be the first set of object in your 'envelope.json'

Comment: I changed $('[name=ticketcode]') to $('input[name=ticketcode]'). I can't see the difference. I would like to print the values in from JSON file based on the user request eg."2955500":[23, "Returned", "http://www.dhl.com/html/track_and_trace.html?q=PX1001580103110084&btnG=go", "Additional informatio"],

Comment: We need to see the actual json...

Comment: Try this http://174.120.20.162/~thesuper/envelope.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Caching issues...**

Note that IE is the only browser platform that utilizes caching in AJAX requests because they treat an AJAX request no different then a normal browser request.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ticketsearch').click(function() {
        var ticketcode = $('[name=ticketcode]').val();
        $.getJSON('/import/envelope.json', function(data) {
            $('.ticket').text(data[ticketcode][3]);
            $('.envstatus').text(data[ticketcode][1]);
            $('.track').text(data[ticketcode][2]);
            $('.track').attr("href", data[ticketcode][2]);
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });       // <------this will disable caching
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thak you for quick reply. I have no trailing comma at the end. http://174.120.20.162/~thesuper/envelope.json

Comment: The last time I faced this issue I just added a timestamp to the json URL, I didn't know about this much cleaner "cache: false".  Shouldn't this call to $.ajaxSetup() be outside of the $.getJSON function callback?  it seems like the cache mode is being set after the JSON is requested

Comment: ... the first time, but sure it's more a matter of preference where you put it, it is a global option.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add following code in your jsp page head section

```
<script src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js" />
```

Try this one and check.